# Unexpected print output for python string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to print some values using `str.format`. However, I am getting the first value repeated, which I do not understand. Any help will be appreciated.

```
for tel in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4']:
    print(tel+':{0:.2f}, {0:.2f}, {0:.2f}'.format(0.56, 0.12, 0.25))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the zero in `{0:.2f}` which means 'argument at index 0', so you call always the same, just remove it, and it'll use arguments in their order

```
for tel in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4']:
    print(tel + ':{:.2f}, {:.2f}, {:.2f}'.format(0.56, 0.12, 0.25))
```

Answer (score 3):

The first entry in curly braces is the index of the list you reference in the format statement. So you always take the first entry by saying {0:x}. What you need to do is:

```
print(tel+':{0:.2f}, {1:.2f}, {2:.2f}'.format(0.56, 0.12, 0.25))
```

or leave it empty like {:x}.

Answer (score 1):

The number before `:` is the index of the argument in `format()` so you are selecting the first argument in all three places. You should use `{:.2f}` instead of `{0:.2f}`.